# Take a value 5 and convert it to json object

Tags: json, jsonata

i should take a JSON value, like

```
{
  "cnt": 5
}
```

and create JSON object from JSONata, like

```
{
  "1": 1,
  "2": 4,
  "3": 9,
  "4": 16,
  "5": 25,
}
```

I tried to do that, but i cant join two expressions correctly.

```
{
"" & [1..cnt] : [1..cnt].($*$)
}
```

and i get as a result:

```
{
  "[1,2,3,4,5]": [
    1,
    4,
    9,
    16,
    25
  ]
}
```

Can anybody help me with this(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `[1..cnt]{$string($): $*$}`

See https://try.jsonata.org/SVapg4fzt